# Intel XDK More than one cordova.js script?

Tags: javascript, cordova, intel-xdk

I'm trying to build an app using Intel XDK, and I'm running into problems. Things were going well at first, but this morning I was prompted to update XDK, and now my app isn't working.

My login page works fine, and the resulting page with links to various pages in the app work. But when I click a link, the page loads, but is blank, and then I get a JS alert saying:

"It appears you have more than one script tag for cordova.js. There can only be one!"

I found the  tag and commented it out to see what would happen, and the only thing that changed was I didn't get the alert. The page is still blank. The only coding I've done was the login script on the index page, so I don't know why it broke. I tried restarting the program, and even recreating the app, and it's doing the same thing. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimenting, I've come to realize that the problem was I was using List View buttons to navigate, and I was navigating to a different page altogether. That was causing my problem. I just combined all of the pages into one, and it works fine, now.

Answer (score 0):

There were a variety of changes to the Emulate tab with the new version. I get the impression you're using the Emulate tab. I recommend that you test with the Debug tab on a real device, it will give more accurate results.